# Proposition 2.3 (Cyclic Groups) in Dummit and Foote

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

On page 55 of *Abstract Algebra* in the proof of Proposition 2.3, it is assumed that $n=|x|$. I don't understand why $n$ has to be equal to $|x|$. Please help to clarify this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not all math.stackexchange users have this book so you should post the proposition and its proof as given in the book.

Comment: I've added a picture but perhaps it's a different edition. The text is not particularly clear at that point. I see you confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof starts with:

> Let $|x|=n$ and...

This *defines* $n$ to be the order of $|x|$. It is not an assumption.

Comment: Oops, I confused order of x with absolute value of x...